# Images not being shown in HTML Page

Tags: html, angular

Image doesn't show when I open the page, while I double checked the image file exists there
here is my code.

```
<h3>Employees Directory</h3>
<div class="row">
<div *ngFor="let randomdata of randomdata">
    <div class="card" style="height: 300px;width:250px;">
        <img class="card-img-top" style="width:150px;" src="/src/images/avatar.png" alt='Employee Image'>
        <div class="card-body">
            <p>First Name: {{randomdata.first_name}}</p>
            <p>Last Name: {{randomdata.last_name}}</p>
            <p>Gender: {{randomdata.gender}}</p>
            <p>Email: {{randomdata.email}}</p>
            <p>Street Address:{{randomdata.location}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried changing src quotations to single quotations as well.

Comment: ```randomdata of randomdata``` ? why same variables?

Comment: Try this: remove "/src/" from img src if you have not a folder with name "src"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the image location under the assets folder and update the link to

```
  <img src="/assets/images/avatar.png">
```

Comment: yes it worked, 
Why was it not working previously, even though the path was correct

Comment: I don't know but I guess it's a path problem

Answer (score 1):

You should consider changing the variable name to

```
let randomObj of randomdata
```

and use [src]

```
<img class="card-img-top" style="width:150px;" [src]="./images/avatar.png" alt='Employee Image'>
```

Comment: That's not working too
I want to use the same image for every object, 
the exact path to my image is:
    E:\OfficeSpace\OfficeSpace\src\images\avatar.png

Comment: Nothing, it doesn't display any error. 
While my console says:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: which means your url is wrong. open the url in browser and paste it here

Comment: I've double check the URL.
Remember: This is an angular application

Comment: when I paste my URL
file:///E:/OfficeSpace/OfficeSpace/src/images/avatar.png
in browser, it displays the image instantly

Comment: i know dude, are you hosting the application in a server or just browsing the HTML?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197149/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-james-leborn).

Comment: Try to use without /src/. This src="images/avatar.png"